# còmo sumar valores en realtime database firebase android

Tags: android, sql, base-de-datos, firebase

estoy tratando de sumar valores recuperados de realtime database

por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
ganancias= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ganancias").child("semana1");

    ganancias.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {


        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error){}
    });
```

Se supone que snapshot contiene todos los dìas, pero ¿còmo recorro el total y sumarlos?

Answer (score 0):

Para sumar valores y actualizarlo en la base de datos ( en caso de que sea necesario) debes:

1. Obtienes el valor actual desde Firebase Realtime Database.
2. Haces las operaciones pertinentes con el dato.
3. Lo insertas de nuevo en la base de datos ( en caso de que quieras actualizarlo ahí).

Los valores los obtienes con `snapshot.getValue();`

Debes entender que un conjunto de datos en **RealTime Database es como tratar con un JSON**. Solo debes ir accediendo a los elementos y a sus sub-elementos.

La propia documentación de Firebase para android lo explica correctamente:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Aquí algo más de ayuda por si lo necesitas:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data?hl=es

Comment: Serìa buena idea agregar un ejemplo.